# Draw view over call screen on oreo device

Tags: android, overlay, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to show popup view (like truecaller) on the incoming call screen. It is working fine on an emulator for oreo and all the devices till nougat, in both cases locked and unlocked. But on One Plus 5t (oreo) it is just working while the device is unlocked. When the device is locked, view is just behind the incoming call screen.

I am trying to add a view using service by given LayoutParams

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            AppLog.showLog(CLASS_TAG, "Device is oreo");
            params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        } else {
            AppLog.showLog(CLASS_TAG, "Device is less than oreo");
            params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        params1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Is there anything I am missing?? Please help...

Comment: Yes. In order to do that on Android M(6.0) or above devices, the app needs to have `Draw over other apps` permission. It is different from normal permission. User have to go to settings and enable it. Read more about it here https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9

Comment: thanks for your reply. if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } if this is what you are talking about, then I did it already. but it's not working. service starts but view is not showing over incoming call screen.

Comment: Hi man... did you solve this issue?

Comment: add flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer possible to draw over the lockscreen and other important UI elements (status bar, etc) Google removed this feature in Android O.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36574245